# Android Studio AVD not detecting JRE

Tags: java, android, linux, ubuntu, android-studio

I am running Ubuntu 14.10.
I recently installed Android Studio on my laptop.
When I try to run the AVD, I get the following error
[image: error]

When I try java -version in the terminal, it shows I have JDK and JRE installed.
[image: terminal]

This is the path I've specified
[image: terminal2]

I've tried changing the path but no luck.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not a shell script you can not write any shell variable with **'$'** sign. You have to just concatenate (using **':'** operator) the `JAVA_HOME/bin` directory in your `/etc/environment` file like this -

```
JAVA_HOME=/user/local/jdk1.8.0_45
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/user/local/jdk1.8.0_45/bin"

export JAVA_HOME #invalid in /etc/environment; don't place export here
export PATH #invalid in /etc/environment; don't place export here
```

From in `/etc/environment` you don't need to export the environment variables.

**Note:** export is invalid in `/etc/environment` since it is not a shell/bash file. `/etc/environment/` is just a configuration file which is read by the `OS` during boot and all setting is loaded in that time. And finally the configuration written int `/etc/environment` will be applicable for all over the environment and for all users.

Comment: After making any change in /etc/environment you have to source it using the following command - 'sourcce /etc/environment'. Then you can get the chagnes only from terminal. If you want to get the changes from whole system then you have to restart your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to install Open JDK from Ubuntu software center and then you don't need to do any path operations.